# Can we have V=HPD? And is it equivalent to V=HOD?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I've lately came to know that the axiom $\sf V=HOD$ can be stated as:  $$\forall X \, \exists \theta \, \exists \alpha < \theta \, \exists \varphi :  X=\{y \in V_\theta\mid V_\theta\models\varphi(y,\alpha)\}$$
Now my question: is it possible along the same general lines to state the following axiom: $$\forall X \, \exists \theta \, \exists p_1,..,p_n \in V_\theta \, \exists \varphi : \\ X=\{y \in V_\theta\mid V_\theta\models\varphi(y,p_1,..,p_n)\}$$ Call that as $\sf V= HPD$, for *Hereditarily Parameteric Definable*.

Notice that here the parameters $p_1,..,p_n$ in the above axiom are not restricted to being ordinals.

If that is possible, then is it equivalent to $\sf V=HOD$ over the rest of axioms of $\sf ZF$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I claim that $\sf ZF$ already proves $\sf V=HPD$. Moreover, it is enough to restrict ourselves to a single atomic formula: $\varphi(y,p):=y\in p$.

For every $X$, there exists a $\theta$ such that $X\in V_\theta$, so we may take $p=X$, and then we have, with our chosen $\varphi$ $$X=\{y\in V_\theta\mid V_\theta\models y\in X\}.$$

So this axiom is most certainly not equivalent to $\sf V=HOD$.

Comment: hmmm..., I think I need to add that $X \not \in V_\theta$, in order to cut this argument of yours.

Comment: In that case you are requiring that $X$ is definable in its rank. That clearly cannot happen, since the definability here is internal, so there are only $|V_\theta|$ definable subsets of $V_\theta$, whereas $V_{\theta+1}$ has a lot more elements, what with being the power set of $V_\theta$.

Comment: I'm thinking of ways to cut the cyclicity involved in your argument, like by requiring $  X \not \subseteq \text{tcl} (p_i)$ for every parameter $p_i$, i.e. $X$ is not a subset of the transitive closure of any of the parameters.